# Applying for NSF (Math Fellowship) before being accepted to a university. How to find a Sponsor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, nsf

I am in the process of applying to graduate schools this Fall 2017 (both in the US and in Europe). I do not yet know what institution I may go to nor do I know any researcher who would be willing to make such early plans. I am wondering whether or not my case matches the requirements of the [NSF (Math Fellowship)](https://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5301&org=NSF)? I have read the FAQs but found nothing that answers my concern.

From [the description for Sponsoring Scientist](https://www.nsf.gov/mps/dms/MSPRF/MSPRF_fastlane_instructions_host_institutions.pdf), I read

```
The sponsoring scientist's statement is meant to
show how the host and host institution will provide a vibrant and
supportive environment for the Fellow's proposed research and
training activities and provide a basis for the Fellow's future
independent research career.
```

The above makes me think that this Fellowship is only appropriate for enrolled students. Is this right?

If not and it is indeed possible/appropriate for me to apply for NSF (Math Fellowship), then how should I go about finding a Sponsoring Scientist? Is it appropriate to approach/email some researchers in some schools that I will be applying to?

Comment: The PDF you linked to is for a postdoc fellowship, not a student fellowship.

Comment: You probably want the [NSF Graduate Research Fellowship Program](http://www.nsfgrfp.org/).

Comment: That explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the NSF Mathematical Sciences **Postdoctoral** Research Fellowships, which is for funding postdocs, not graduate study.

You probably want the [NSF Graduate Research Fellowship](http://www.nsfgrfp.org/), which is the main NSF fellowship program for PhD studies in math and science.  This program doesn't have a "sponsoring scientist" requirement.